# Redmine Appliance Project-Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtualbox, redmine, winscp

This is my situation (I'm using Windows 8.1):

I'm using the [Turnkey Linux Redmine Appliance](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/redmine) with [Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/). Installation and Configuration worked fine and Redmine is running how it's supposed.

The problem is I need to configure files inside the Redmine project directory. To get access to the files of my Virtual Machine Appliance I'm using [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php). It's also working fine but I can't find my project directory.

The book I use ([Mastering Redmine](http://www.amazon.de/Mastering-Redmine-Andriy-Lesyuk/dp/1849519145)) says (for example) the `configuration.yml` file should be in the directory:

```
/root/usr/share/redmine
```

But I cant even find the redmine folder inside the share folder..
I hope someone knows where the project folder is and could say me the path.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: check `/var/www/railsapp` (taken from [Turnkey](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20110201/upgrading-redmine) forums)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm wondered that I didn't find it but four eyes are better than two ;) Please write your comment as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check `/var/www/railsapp` (taken from [Turnkey](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20110201/upgrading-redmine) forums)